# A question about $G_\delta$ sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How does one show that for any $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, there is a $G \in G_\delta$ such that $E \subset G$ and $m_* (E) = m_*(G)$?

$m_*$ stands for outer measure and $G_\delta $ set is re sets that are the countable intersection of open sets.

I was thinking since we don't know anything about $E$, we could look at its $int(E)$ which is open and maybe construct something along the lines of $E \subset \bigcap_{r} int(E) \cup B_{r}(0)$.

I am mostly having trouble coming up the reasons for the existence of $G$.

Comment: $E$ does not have to be measurable, since we are showing $m_*(G) - m_*(E) = 0$, not $m_*(G - E) = 0$.

Comment: @Xiao, how do you know that $m_∗(E)$ exist? If E is not measurable, $m_∗(E)$ may not exist.

Comment: @Hawk, you better use standard symbol for outer measure, which is $m^∗(E)$. $m_∗(E)$ is normally inner measure.

Comment: @hermes By the usual definition, the outer measure is defined on  $2^{\mathbb{R}^n}$, so  it is defined to ANY set $E \subseteq  \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @hermes  Outer measures have $\inf$ taken over a subset of $[0,+\infty]$. Such $\inf$ always exists.  (It exists even in the case of the empty subset, however such case does not happen in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: @hermes There is not just one Vitali set. Each choice  of representatives of the equivalence classes for relation on $\mathbb{[0,1]}$ given by $y−x\in \mathbb{Q}$ yields **a** Vitali set. All Vitali sets (contained in $[0,1]$) have outer Lebesgue measure greater than $0$ and less or equal to$1$.

Comment: @hermes Learn the definitions.

Comment: @hermes I hope this helps to make it clearer for you. Let $V\subseteq[0,1]$ be **a** Vitali set. Since $V\subseteq[0,1]$,
$$ \{\sum_{n=0}^\infty m(I_n) \,|\, V \subseteq \bigcup I_n\} \supseteq \{m([0,1])\}$$  
So we have:   $ 1 \in \{\sum_{n=0}^\infty m(I_n) \,|\, V \subseteq \bigcup I_n\} \subseteq [0,\infty] $. So 
$$ 0 \leqslant \inf\{\sum_{n=0}^\infty m(I_n) \,|\, V \subseteq \bigcup I_n\} \leqslant 1$$
So $0 \leqslant m^*(V) \leqslant 1 $. We can exclude $m^∗(V)=0$ because $V$ is non-measurable. So we have $0 < m^*(V) \leqslant 1 $.

Comment: @hermes No, we don't need to prove that $m(V)$ is the $\inf$.  The $\inf$ exists and it is, by definition of outer measure, $m^*(V)$. You seem to be confusing "outer measure" with some kind of "outer regular measure".

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: When I wrote this answer I mistakenly thought the question was about outer measure on $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb R^n$. Things are not quite so trivial in $\Bbb R^n$. There will be a version for $\Bbb R^n$ appearing here when I have time. Thanks to Nate Eldrege for pointing out the problem.

---

This is obvious. Say $m_*(E)=\alpha$. By definition $\alpha$ is the infimum of the measure of $V$ such that $V$ is an open set with $E\subset V$. Hence there exist open sets $V_n$ with $E\subset V_n$ and $m(V_n)\to\alpha$.

Let $G=\bigcap V_n$. Then $G\subset V_n$ for every $n$, so $m_*(G)\le m_*(V_n)$ for every $n$, hence $m_*(G)\le\lim m_*(V_n)=
\alpha$. On the other hand, $E\subset G$ so $\alpha=m_*(E)\le m_*(G)$.

Comment: Gonna sound dumb, but how do we know $\alpha$ exists? Is having a measure and being measurability not really the same?

Comment: ??? We _defined_ $\alpha$ to be $m_*(E)$ is how we know it exists...

Comment: I mean how do we know $m_*(E)$ exists?  Isn't that only after we know $E$ is measurable?

Comment: You're trying to solve problems about this stuff even though you don't know the definitions. That's impossible.

Comment: @Hawk the Lebesgue outer measure is defined on all power set of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I believe that in the last sentence of your answer you meant: "... so $\alpha=m_*(E)\le m_*(G)$".

Comment: @Ramiro thanks...

Comment: As to your "by definition", this is only one possible definition of Lebesgue outer measure. Some books define it as the infimum over covers of E by countable unions of closed rectangles, or something similar, in which case one has to do more work to show your statement. (Actually, since one commonly uses outer measure to define measure, your definition risks being circular.)

Comment: @NateEldredge All excellent points, sadly. It seems at least _possible_ you're curious how I came to say such moronic things. I missed the fact that the problem was about $\Bbb R^n$, assumed it was about $\Bbb R$, where things are much less problematic. Will revise post when I have time. (When I do this stuff, on $\Bbb R$, I define $|V|$ for open sets $V$ to be the sum of the lengths of the components, emphasizing that we shouldn't call it $m(V)$ yet, then I define $m_*(E)$ to be the inf of $|V|$. No problem there - yes, in $\Bbb R^n$ things are not quite that simple.)